# Mysql unique query to get all tags associated in one row

Tags: mysql

I am designing a tag system with PHP and MySql. Websites (table 1) are associated to many tags (table 2) in a third table (table 3):

table1:

```
! ----- ! -----------------!
! t1_id ! t1_libelle       ! 
! ----- ! ---------------- !
! 1     ! Site 1           ! 
! ----- ! ---------------- !
! 2     ! Site 2           !
```

table2:

```
! t2_id ! tag             ! 
! ----- ! ----------------!
! 3     ! Référencement   ! 
! ----- ! ----------------!
! 4     ! Linking         ! 
! ----- ! ----------------! 
! 5     ! HTML            !
```

table3:

```
! t1_id ! t2_id     ! 
! ----- ! ----------!
! 1     ! 3         ! 
! ----  ! --------- !
! 1     ! 4         ! 
! ----  ! --------- ! 
! 2     ! 4         ! 
! ----  ! --------- !
! 2     ! 5         !
```

I am looking for a unique query to returns all tags associated to one website in only one row. Currently I extract websites first then I run a second query (in a PHP 'for') to get the associated tags for each website.

So I would like to have only one row for a website, something similar as follows (I need both tags ids and names):

```
! ----- ! -----------------!---------------!-------------------------!
! t1_id ! t1_libelle       ! table2.t2_id  ! tags                    ! 
! ----- ! ---------------- !---------------!------------------------ !
! 1     ! Site 1           ! 3, 4          ! Référencement, Linking  !  
! ----- ! ---------------- !---------------!-------------------------!
! 2     ! Site 2           ! 4, 5          ! Linking, HTML           !
```

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You mention PHP, so consider handling issues of data display in your application level code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use group_concat  and group by

```
select table1.t1_id, table1.t1_libelle, group_concat(table2.t2_id), group_concat(table2.tag)
from table1
inner join table3 on table_3.t1_id = table1.t1_id
inner join table2 on table_3.t2_id = table2.t2_id
group by table1.t1_id, table1.t1_libelle
```